When running a Support Vector Machine, how do I formulate the linear transformation that flips the decision hyperplane in the non-augmented dimension?
We know that when running a support vector machine, we actually use the "kernel trick" to compute the decision hyperplane (boundary) as if we do so in the kernel-augmented dimension, but not actually in the kernel-augmented dimension. My question is, if there is some transformation in the kernel-augmented dimension, such as a linear transformation that flips the decision hyperplane, how can this transformation be mathematically formulated using lower dimensional variables, similar to the way the kernel trick works?
